# Hide CSS scroll bar till max-width and max-height condition are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a scroll bar when the content inside div exceeds max-width.

Following is the code snippet to display the scroll positions. But the problem is , the scroll bar is appearing even when there is nothing to scroll. if we run the following snippet in full-screen mode , then we can notice , the scroll bars are visible by default. I need them to appear only when max-width or max-height constrains are meet.

```css
.scrollbar{
    height: 150px;
    overflow:scroll;  
}

.big-box{
  height:800px;
  width:1000px;
  background-color:#A8D0DB;
}
```

```html
   <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">   
      <div class="big-box"></div>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g6fehv2w/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `overflow: auto`, which only shows a scrollbar when the content overflows.

You can set `overflow-y` to `auto` to only show a scrollbar when the vertical content overflows and `overflow-x` to `auto` to only show a scrollbar when the horizontal content overflows.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).